# Unable to get image from url using NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: image, url, proxy, nsurlconnection

I have a special URL that returns an image in a browser. I'd like to put this special image into a UIImage object. However, in my code sample below, it seems that the data returned is not an image.

The browser seems to know about the image, how can I get to the image?

Yes, I need get this image via the proxify proxy server to solve an issue we have.

Here is the sample code.

```
-(UIImage*)retrieveMap
{        
    NSString* proxifiedGoogleMapURL = @"http://proxify.com/p/011010A1000100/687474703a2f2f6d6170732e676f6f676c652e636f6d2f6d6170732f6170692f7374617469636d61703f63656e7465723d34312e3031343130312c2d3130342e393738333333267a6f6f6d3d362673697a653d35303678353036267363616c653d32266d6170747970653d726f61647326666f726d61743d706e672673656e736f723d66616c7365";  

    NSURLRequest * firstRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: proxifiedGoogleMapURL]];
    NSURLResponse * firstResponse = nil; 
    NSError * firstError = nil;
    NSData* firstData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:firstRequest returningResponse:&firstResponse error:&firstError];

    UIImage* dataAsImage = [UIImage imageWithData:firstData];


    if(firstError != nil || dataAsImage == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed in retrieving the map");
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Succeeded in retrieving the map");
    }

    return dataAsImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted a few problems:

1. You should test `firstError != nil` before you try to convert to an UIImage. Testing it after kind of makes it useless.
2. I've tried to access that URL you posted and I got an error saying it is available only to users logged in. In the browser it might work for you since you are probably logged in, but the iphone is not and you get that HTML from proxify
3. To see the response you get, before creating the image convert it to NSString and display it to the console:

`NSLog(@"Response from server: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:firstData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`